# How do I build up a payload in Mule?

Tags: mule, payload, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I want to make 3 calls to different systems and want to add the information from each query result to the payload object.

My experience up to now is that the query result from call 2 would overwrite call 1 so what is the best way to add the values to the payload without overwriting it as I need call 1-3 to populate a main JSON object?

I'm currently trying to figure out the best design for this so no example XML at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: save each payload in a variable and at last you can use dataweave to combine those.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is you can use Mule `message enricher` and inside it, you can call other query and store the result in a variable. Using a message enricher will not overwrite the existing payload and let you to store all the query result in a variable.
You can find message enricher reference here :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/message-enricher

Now, once you stored all the results of the calls in variables using enricher, if you need to combine the main payload with those, you can use either a [Dataweave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation) component or an [expression transformer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/expression-transformer-reference) to populate and modify existing JSONpayload